# How do we encode mysql special character in PhP?

Tags: php, mysql

I make this php program to access mysql data

```
foreach ($arrayOfID as $ID)     {
    $IDWhere[]="TB.ID LIKE '" .$ID."'";
    //$IDWhereOther[]="Business LIKE '".$ID."'";
    //  $IDWhereFinalOther1[]=$ID;
    $IDWherePhone[]="BusinessID LIKE '".$ID."'";
    //$IDWhereURLandImage[]="`Business ID` LIKE '".$ID."'";
    $newOutput[$ID]=array();
    $copy[$ID]=array(); 
    keyID2[]=$ID;
    $IDtoBuilding[]="TB.ID LIKE '".$ID."'";
}
IDWhereFinal=implode(" OR ", $IDWhere);
//$IDWhereFinalOther=implode(" OR ", $IDWhereOther);
//$IDFinalBuilding=implode(" OR ", $IDtoBuilding);  
//$query="Select *, Country FROM `tablebusiness` As TB, `tablecity` As TC WHERE (".$IDWhereFinal.") AND TB.City=TC.City";
//$query="Select *, Country, Building.Title FROM `tablebusiness` As TB, `tablecity` As TC, `tablebusiness` As Building WHERE (".$IDWhereFinal.") AND TB.City=TC.City And (Building.ID=TB.Building OR TB.Building=0)";
 //$query="Select *, Country, COALESCE(NULL,(select Title from `tablebusiness` As TBuild where  TBuild.ID=TB.Building)) as BuildingTitle FROM `tablebusiness` As TB,  `tablecity` As TC, `tablebusiness` As Building WHERE (".$IDWhereFinal.") AND TB.City=TC.City";
$query="Select *, Country, (select Title from `tablebusiness` As TBuild where TBuild.ID=TB.Building) as BuildingTitle FROM `tablebusiness` As TB, `tablecity` As TC WHERE TB.City=TC.City and (".$IDWhereFinal.")";
$data = mysql_query($query);
```

Problem is, sometimes `$ID` contains `'`

I think that should be escaped into `''`

But `'` may not be the only problem

Maybe there are other characters that should be encoded too.

Is there a function for that?

Comment: Read about `mysql_real_escape_string` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. You have to use `mysql_real_escape_string`. THat's also good for security, basically you should put everytime you insert data in you DB (unless it's not a string, then a cast to int/float/etc is OK)

Answer (score 1):

The modern way of doing this is to use PHP's PDO extension and prepared statements which can handle the correct escaping for you. So your query would become something like this

```
Select *, Country, (
    select Title from `tablebusiness` As TBuild 
    where TBuild.ID=TB.Building) as BuildingTitle 
FROM `tablebusiness` As TB, `tablecity` As TC 
WHERE TB.City=TC.City and (TB.ID LIKE ? OR BusinessID LIKE ?)
```

Comment: are there introduction to PDO tutorial? the documentation is not good